# Can I write a method body without curly braces {}?

Tags: java, methods, curly-braces

I know in loops or if statements, one can write it like this:

```java
if(x>4) System.out.println("Hello world!"); // No curly braces
```

I'm wondering, am I allowed to do the same thing with methods or classes?

E.g.

```java
public static void example() System.out.println("Hello world!"); // No curly braces
```

Or do I have to write curly braces for methods and classes?

Comment: Short answer: no.  Longer answer: nooooooo.

Comment: No  because curly braces are used to define the start and end of a code block ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Curly braces are **required for methods**.

From the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/index.html):

[Method Body](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.7)

> A method body is either a block of code that implements the method or
> simply a semicolon, indicating the lack of an implementation.

[What is a block?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-14.html#jls-Block)

> A block is a sequence of statements, local class declarations, and
> local variable declaration statements **within braces**.

Also **required for classes.**

[Class Body and Member Declarations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-8.html#jls-ClassBodyDeclaration)

> ClassBody:
> **{** {ClassBodyDeclaration} **}**

*Bold formatting is mine.

Answer (score 4):

Well, technically you don't need to write any curly braces:

```
public static void example() \u007b System.out.println("Hello world!"); \u007d
```

Comment: this is glorious

Comment: Okay. Very interesting :)

Comment: \u263A \u263A \u263A

Answer (score 0):

Not in java, but in other languages that are based on the JVM, like Kotlin, you can directly return the result of a single expression.

Example:

```
fun example() = "Hello world!"
```